# Load custom cell from nib issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have my custom `CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell` with `@property(nonatomic, retain) Model* model;`. There is also xib file with one view (cell with properly configured class and reuse identifier). In my custom cell class, there is an `- init` implementation:

```
- (id)init
{
    NSArray* array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    CustomTableViewCell* cell = [[array firstObject] retain];
    self = cell;

    self.model = [[Model alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.model.someString = @"foo";

    // here I can access self.model with no problem
    return self;
    // after method return, self.model refers to 0x0
}
```

My problem is... after the returning of the `- init`, `self.model` is nil. Cell is working, but without `model`. And I don't know why. Any ideas? I think, my `- init` is not kosher...

## EDIT

I found out, the model is nil no after return, but when table view data source methods are called. Also table view refers to 0x0 in that time what totally amazes me. Totally weird! Thank you for your endeavor, I'm going to do my cell in code...

Comment: When you say you can access self.model without any problem, what do you mean? You can see a valid object when logging or in the debugger, or just that you don't get any runtime errors from the init method?

Comment: It does seem an unusual pattern to have your cell hold a "model" - obviously I don't know what it is in the context of your app, but if it refers to the data displayed in the cell then this isn't the normal way of doing things, due to cell reuse. Your cell would normally be loaded from a custom xib during the table view data source cellforrowatindexpath method, and any data passed to it at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Have you synthesised model in the implementation?

```
@synthesize model;
```

Comment: Yes. Also I `release` it in `- dealloc`.

Answer (score 2):

you should not use dot property syntax for your ivars in your init method. Basically because the entire object may not be completely setup up yet.  Try this:

```
model=[Model alloc] init];
model.someString=@"foo";
```

also you should check to see if self is not nil before going doing anything else with your ivars

good luck.

Answer (score 2):

1. you need to check the result from `[Model alloc] init]`, make sure value is not nil.
2. check your property `model` of the cell, make sure it's not assign.
3. if still the `model` of `cell` is nil, please posts more codes here.